# does linux docker work better on particular file type?

Tags: files, docker

I am building a Linux Docker system.
Should I use ext4 or is there any need for XFS?

Comment: I don't think docker *cares* what filesystem it's on...

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/ - if you're using the default `overlay2` storage driver, it works fine with `ext4` or `xfs`, so use whatever your system has (probably `ext4`)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Docker documentation on docker storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/), the default Linux storage driver is `overlay2`.

Both `ext4` and `xfs` are backend filesystems that support the `overlay2` file system.  You don't need to switch from `ext4` to `xfs` just because of Docker; you should be OK with the default `ext4` filesystem that Ubuntu installs.